# Ruby one-liners: Writing a — POSIX shell compatible — TSV format

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a **concise** way of outputting TSV records that can be accurately read and unescaped with a POSIX shell (`IFS='<TAB>' read -r` + `printf %b`).

The minimalist escaping rules are:

- `\\` for backslash
- `\n` for newline
- `\t` for tab
- `\r` for carriage return

But they can be extended to the  [full supported set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_13) of `printf`, if there exists an easy way of doing it with ruby.

The code so far:

```rb
record = [ "\\", "\t", "\n", "\r", "\"" ]

rules = {
  "\\" => "\\\\",
  "\t" => "\\t",
  "\r" => "\\r",
  "\n" => "\\n"
};

regex = /#{ rules.keys.map{|c| Regexp.escape(c)}.join(?|) }/;

puts record.map { |field| field.gsub(regex) {|c| rules[c]} }.join("\t")
```

Output:

```
\\  \t  \n  \r  "
```

The main problem is that the code is meant for one-liners, thus, if possible, I would like to reduce it greatly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, every program can always be written as a one-liner, since line breaks are optional: every function that a line break can have (expression separator, introducing a syntactic block, etc.) can also be performed by a symbol (e.g. `;` as expression separator) or keyword (e.g. `then` for introducing the consequence block of a conditional expression or `case` expression or `do` to introduce the body of a `while` or `for` loop, etc.)

For example, your code can be written as a one-liner like this:

```ruby
record = [ "\\", "\t", "\n", "\r", "\"" ]; rules = { "\\" => "\\\\", "\t" => "\\t", "\r" => "\\r", "\n" => "\\n" }; regex = /#{ rules.keys.map{|c| Regexp.escape(c)}.join(?|) }/; puts record.map { |field| field.gsub(regex) {|c| rules[c]} }.join("\t")
```

However, there are some possible improvements we can make to the code.

Use [`Regexp::union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to construct `regex`:

```ruby
regex = Regexp.union(rules.keys)
```

Since you already went through the trouble of constructing a replacement `Hash`, why not use the form of [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) that [takes a replacement `Hash` as an argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#class-String-label-Substitution+Methods):

```ruby
puts record.map { |field| field.gsub(regex, rules) }.join("\t")
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very insightful. I didn't think of using Regexp::union; also, I didn't know that String::gsub could take a hash as argument; it makes things a lot easier.